# Como enviar parametro a un controlador con ajax laravel

Tags: laravel, ajax

buen dia

quiero enviar el contenido de un input por ajax a un controlador para que dentro de este sea parametro de consulta en mi base de datos  pero no se como hacerlo esto es lo que llevo

gracias de antemano

** controlador**

```
public function form_1 ($lineas){
    

    $historial=flineone::where('codigo_formualario',PARAMETRO AJAX )->get();
    $Registrouno =Registrouno::all();
    $linea = linea::all();
    $ing = Personas::where('cargo','INGENIERO DE PLANTA')->get();

    if($lineas=='linea1'){
        
        return view('formulario1',compact('Registrouno' , 'linea','lineas','ing','historial'));

    }else if($lineas=='linea2'){
       
        return view('formulario2',compact('Registrouno' , 'linea','lineas','ing','historial'));


    }
```

donde dice PARAMETRO AJAX  es donde deseo que se traiga el valor del input con ajax

**ajax**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#btn_procesos').click(function(){


// asignacion de variables a usar 
 var codigo =$('#cformulario').val; 
 

 //obteniendo los datos del codigo para busqueda

 function busquedahistorial(){

    $.ajax({

        url:"{route('gethistorial')}",
        type:'GET',
        dataType:'json', 
        data:{codigo:codigo},

        success:function(data){

            alert('se recogieron los datos correctamente');
        }
    });
    
 }
})

})
```

**ruta**

```
Route::get('publisher/gethistorial',[PagesController::class,'gethistorial'])->name('gethistorial');
```

se supone que aqui recojo el dato  pero como lo puedo usar en mi controlador como parametro de consulta

Comment: debes corregir `data:{codigo}` en el ajax ya que si el valor de `#cformulario` es `hola` enviaria `{"hola" : "hola"}`

Comment: gracias por tu comentario pero tienes un ejemplo similiar para poder aplicarlo  :(

Comment: Como lo estas mandando desde el formulario? Puedes compartir ese bloque?

Comment: en si no lo estoy guardando si no que cada vez que cambia este input deberia ejecutar la consulta para mostrar apenas se ingrese un nuevo registro el valor lo recojo con   $('#codigo_formulario).val();  cada vez que se de click

Comment: Tienes varios errores en los nombres checa esa parte tal vez por ahí esté el error. Por ejemplo: “ codigo_formualario”, y tal vez quiziste escribir “FileOne” para referenciar a este modelo; “ flineone” ?

Answer (score 0):

Según las especificaciones de Laravel, todos los controladores que vayan a recibir una petición, serán manejados por un objet **Request** que, por lo general estará instanciado dentro de la función pública que querramos usar, indistintamente del verbo que querramos usar. Además, Laravel proporciona el helper [request()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request) para poder manejar estas peticiones también.

Sabiendo esto, tu controlador debería quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
public function form_1 (Request $request){


$historial=flineone::where('codigo_formualario', $request['PARAMETRO AJAX'] )->get();
$Registrouno =Registrouno::all();
$linea = linea::all();
$ing = Personas::where('cargo','INGENIERO DE PLANTA')->get();

if($request['lineas']=='linea1'){
    
    return view('formulario1',compact('Registrouno' , 'linea','lineas','ing','historial'));

}else if($request['lineas']=='linea2'){
   
    return view('formulario2',compact('Registrouno' , 'linea','lineas','ing','historial'));


}
```

Así tu controlador, habiendo colocado correctamente el controlador en la ruta asignada, podría obtener el Request que estás haciendo desde tu petición AJAX. Así simplemente deberías hacer lo siguiente (Uso fetch por facilidad para mí):

```
const form = document.getElementById('cformulario')

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   
   let data = new FormData(form);
   
   let value1 = data.get('name1')
   
   let value2 = data.get('name2')

   fetch(`/tu/url?paramAjax=${value1}&lineas=${value2}`)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .then(res => window.location.href = 'tu/ruta/nueva')
     .catch(err => console.error(err))

})
```

Lo que hice fue extraer los *names* de tu formulario luego de haber convertido a tu formulario en un objeto [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData) para poder pasarlos a la url que tu necesitas enviar la consulta y esta haga todo el proceso de búsqueda. También se podía hacer dándole un id a cada input y haciendo `idInput.value`.

Te recomendaría que pasaras tu respuesta a un json y esta fuera capturada por tu consulta AJAX para redirigirte a la vista que deseas.

Así el controlador recibirá tu Request y sabrá qué hacer, como lo tienes, sólo acepta un parámetro pero pareciera que no estuviera añadido a ninguna ruta para recibir esa data.

Para más información, [consulta aquí](https://laravel.com/docs)